# Creating a share and granting permissions via cmd.exe and net share

Tags: permissions, cmd, wmi, windows-server-2008, finalbuilder

I am trying to create a share on a Windows Server 2008.

I can do it fine via the GUI and everything works like a charm.

But when I try to do it via the command prompt (I need the command prompt for a FinalBuilder WMI action step), nothing happens.

I use the command:

```
C:\>net share MyShare=d:\MyShareFolder /grant:Everyone,FULL
```

It returns a message like "Share was created", and it is indeed created - but the permissions are not applied.

I originally tried to grant a specific user to the share, but this also fails. The command was this:

```
C:\>net share MyShare=d:\MyShareFolder /grant:domain\myuser,FULL
```

I also tried to use double-quotes around the domain\user-specification, but same result.

There must be something that I am missing - but what is it?

Thanks,

/Jesper

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure that the user have permissions granted to the folder.

Ex.:

```
icacls "d:\MyShareFolder" /grant myuser:(OI)(CI)F
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it fails? It works here. You need quotes if there are spaces in a name.

You do know that file permissions still apply. A user needs share and file permissions.